# 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.' Automapperexception in ASP.NET Core WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I'm trying to add AutoMapper to a API (built using ASP.NET Core 3) but it gives me the 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'-exception and my google-searches doesn't help me at all... :).

The exception is thrown (as described below) in "GetAllObject1"-method

This is my current setup:

```
    [HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAllObject1()
{
    var object1Items = _myService.GetAllObject1();

    Object1ViewModel ouViewModel = _mapper.Map<Object1ViewModel>(Object1Items); // <= This line gives the exception above!!

    return Ok(ouViewModel);
}



 "AutoMapping.cs":

namespace DataAccess.AutoMapper
{
    public class AutoMapping : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapping()
        {
            CreateMap < KollOrganizationalUnit, KollOrganizationalUnitViewModel>();

        }
    }
}
```

"Startup.cs":

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (services == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));

    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

    services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        })
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.RegisterDAL();

        services.RegisterBizServices();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "API",
                Description = "Integration API for XXX",
                TermsOfService = new Uri("https://www.xxx.se/terms-of-service"),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact()
                {
                    Name = "Integrationcontact",
                    Email = "integration@xxx.se",
                    Url = new Uri("https://www.xxx.se")
                },
            });
        });

        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
}
```

Am I missing something obious here?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing the return type of `_myService.GetAllObject1()`, but it seems like it's returning a *collection* of `Object1Unit`. If that's the case, you can try something like:

```cs
IEnumerable<Object1ViewModel> ouViewModels = Object1Items.Select(x => _mapper.Map<Object1ViewModel>(x));
return Ok(ouViewModels);
```

If you're trying to map a collection to a single item, you have to tell AutoMapper how to do that or you will get the exception you're seeing (your `AutoMapping` class only creates a map from a single item to a single item).

Comment: No need for `Select`, just map `Object1Items`.